# Linq skip, take

Tags: linq

I have a list that has 4 rows.
I need to get the value of the 3rd row.

```
    var result = (from rs in list
                  select rs).Skip(2).First();
```

Is there a reason why I would want to use a Take(1) in this scenerio as I have seen used.

```
     var result = (from rs in list
                  select rs).Skip(2).Take(1);
```

Comment: There is never any point in writing `from x in y select x`.

Comment: use directly list.Skip(2).Take(1)

Comment: `list.ElementAt(2)` is all you need, if you know the index of the item you are looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Take(1)` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` containing one object.
`First()` returns the object directly.

Comment: This is actually wrong - `Take(1)` may return an enumerable containing zero objects if the source enumeration is empty.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of the question `Take(1)` is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` *which will contain zero or one element* - so it is similar to `FirstOrDefault()` (besides returning an enumeration).

So to answer you question: no. Use either `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` in this case depending on your expectation of what is in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you want to Get Multiple items skipping the First Two items

```
//Example:
 var result = (from rs in list
                      select rs).Skip(2).Take(5); //Returns 5 items
```